# OpenCV - cvPutText is adding noise to my images

Tags: opencv

I am completely new with OpenCV. I started reading [Learing OpenCV](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/0596516134/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1330288539&sr=8-1) a few days ago and now I would like to do some tests.

I wanted to program an ASCII art conversor. I have done the image iteration and grouped pixels by squares to calculate each region brightness to associate it to a respective character.
So now I need to know how bright is a character in order to link each image region to a character.
My idea was to make another program that gives me the brightness of some characters. The approach is as follows:

- Create an image of size 100*100 (for example) - black background and 1 channel
- Draw the character somewhere in it in white color (cvPutText)
- Iterate the image and count the number of white pixels
- Normalize the result

I think that my program is ok, but I'm getting strange results... Just to check it, I am displaying the images with each character and something strange is going on. The image shows what I am talking about.

[image: cvPutText() result]

This is the code I am using:

```
... 
char c = 'a'; //or whatever
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(150, 150), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

char buffer[7];
sprintf(buffer, "%c", c);

CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 0.5);
cvPutText(img, buffer, cvPoint(2, 15), &font, cvScalar(255));

//iteration to calculate brightness will go here

cvNamedWindow(buffer);
cvShowImage(buffer, img);
cvMoveWindow(buffer, 50*(c-first), 20);
...
```

I am developing on MacOS Lion (if it helps...).
Thank you for reading (and helping!).

Comment: I'm using OpenCV 2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04. I've tried your code snippet, but I didn't see the problem in displaying the image with the character. Just wonder if you do any image manipulation after cvPutText()?

Comment: I think cvCreateImage doesn't initialize the image, have you tried cvSet(img, cvScalar(0,0,0)); ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not using OpenCV any longer but I hope to have time some day in order to continue experimenting with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize the image content: you've just allocate the memory and you see some kind of memory garbage.

Just add [cvSet](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvset#set)(img, cvScalarAll(0)) to set your image to black.

Comment: Thank you for your help too. I will not be able to test the solution in a while, but what you say (and it was said by Milo one month ago too) makes sense. So I approve your answer.

Comment: I have finally retaken this project. I have finished a very simple first version of this. Your solution was great! Thank you (and @Milo too!)

If you are curious about the results, I have uploaded them to my github page: https://github.com/ricardperez/ASCIIArt